# cURL works on Windows but not on WSL2/Debian

Tags: linux, curl, openssl, wsl-2

I'm trying to make a GET request to an old Linux machine using cURL inside WSL2/Debian. The connection between my windows PC and the remote Linux is via VPN. VPN is working as I can ping the IP, as well as VNC to it (via Windows).

The curl command I'm using on WSL2/Debian is:

```
curl -k --header 'Host: 10.48.1.3' --max-time 4 --location --request GET 'https://10.48.1.3/path/to/API/json/get?id=Parameter1&id=Parameter2'
```

Using the verbose option, I get:

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x555661293fb0)
* Expire in 4000 ms for 8 (transfer 0x555661293fb0)
*   Trying 10.48.1.3...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x555661293fb0)
* Connection timed out after 4001 milliseconds
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Connection timed out after 4001 milliseconds
```

After the max-time of 4s the command is cancelled

When I execute the same command on the same computer but using Windows Powershell, it works:

```
curl.exe -k --max-time 4 --location --request GET 'https://10.48.1.3/path/to/API/json/get?id=Parameter1&id=Parameter2' -v
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying 10.48.1.3:443...
* Connected to 10.48.1.3 (10.48.1.3) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* schannel: using IP address, SNI is not supported by OS.
* schannel: ALPN, offering http/1.1
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
Parameter1 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.79.1                                                                                               > Accept: */*                                                                                                           >                                                                                                                       * Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 17 May 2022 15:39:00 GMT
< Server: IosHttp/0.0.1 (MANUFACTURER)
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 239
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
<
PAYLOAD OF API* Connection #0 to host 10.48.1.3 left intact
```

Using Postman inside Windows works also.

Inside WSL2/Debian I'm able to ping the machine, but ssh is not working either; the cursor just stays there blinking without getting back any answer from remote machine:

```
$ ping 10.48.1.3 -c 2
PING 10.48.1.3 (10.48.1.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.48.1.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=61 time=48.9 ms
64 bytes from 10.48.1.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=61 time=28.4 ms

--- 10.48.1.3 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 2ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 28.353/38.636/48.919/10.283 ms
$ ssh -c aes256-cbc root@10.48.1.3
^C   # Cancelled as nothing happened for several minutes
```

On Windows Powershell both, ping and ssh work:

```
> ssh -c aes256-cbc root@10.48.1.3
The authenticity of host '10.48.1.3 (10.48.1.3)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:FINGERPRINTDATAOFMACHINE.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

I've about 100 similar machines on field to which I need to cURL, and this error is coming in about 10 of them, the rest 90 work fine (also on WSL2/Debian).

I guess the error may come from the SSL Version on my WSL2/Debian... Has anyone an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: No, 'SSL version' (in this century really TLS, but everyone understands the old name, just like we still talk about 'dialing' phones) cannot possibly cause connection timeout. Especially not for SSH which is a completely different protocol. Although AIUI WSL2 networking is virtualized I don't know what would cause TCP conn timeout while ICMP still works, except maybe weird settings in iptables. I would look there first, and next at wireshark on the host and tcpdump on the guest to see if SYNs are coming back at all and at which level.